# how to make a full screen width for mobile

Tags: joomla, responsive-design, width, joomla3.4

I think that joomla 3.4 is responsive but I dont know why I get more width in my screen device on my website any help to be full width screen

[image: this how it look like]

thanks alot

Comment: It's down to your template, not Joomla itself. The default Joomla template (Protostar) is responsive but some templates your manually install may not be

Comment: Checking the URL in your screenshot, it doesn't appear you are using Joomla!. Please, give more details as @Lodder suggested.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say withouth a URL, you can use a tool like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or similar for inspect your source code in your browser.

A tool like this will give you information about the selectors and the path where they are located, the line number and the name of the file that contains this selectors. Once you have this you can add or change the values for margin or padding.